# ModuleNotFoundError even if the folder in in the system path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I keep getting a ModuleNotFoundError trying to import a package.
My folder structure is as follow:

```
-system
--has
---element.py
--programs
---ui
----svc.py
```

I have to import element.py into svc.py, here is my code in svc.py:

```
print(sys.path)
from has.element import Element
```

When i run it does print the path and the system folder is indeed in it. But i still get module not found.
I know there are multiple questions very similar but none of them have an answer that worked for me.

Comment: The file name is `element.py` but you are trying to import `elements`.  Is there a `__init__.py` in the `has` folder?

Comment: It was just a typo sorry, but yes there is an __init__.py in the has folder. Still module not found.

Comment: How did you add "system" to `sys.path`?  What you're saying doesn't make sense, so we need to step back.

Comment: I have ```sys.path.insert(0, "mypath")``` at the top of svc.py

Comment: OK, but what path did you provide, exactly?  Did you use a relative path, or an absolute path?  Relative to what?  The answer below (which I may have downvoted unfairly) describes how to generate the path from the location of the script.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're trying to import a module from a different directory. To import element.py into svc.py, you might need to add the path to the system directory explicitly to your Python path.

One way to achieve this is by modifying sys.path in svc.py before importing element.py. Here's how you can do it:

```
import sys
import os

# Get the current directory of svc.py
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Add the 'system' directory to the Python path
system_path = os.path.join(current_dir, '../../')
sys.path.append(system_path)

# Now you can import Element from element.py
from has.element import Element

# Rest of your code
```

Comment: Yes, like i said in the question, i can see the system directory is already in the sys.path with the print(sys.path)

Comment: Did you not see where he said that "system" was in the path?